# Is there a way to view the relationships of just one column in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I´m quite new to the Oracle SQL Developer. I try to handle a big database and I need to define views. Therefore, I need the relationships of some tables. with the relational models of the Browser, I´m able to show ALL relationships of the table, which is quite confusing.

Is there a way to show the ralationships of just one column? 
I want to pick the table and the column and I want to see to which other tables the column is connected.

Thank you.

Comment: You could look at the detail view of a table and see the constraints there. These are pretty much the only way tables/columns would be connected right?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

First find out in which tables the column name has been used :

```
select * from all_tab_columns where column_name='COLUMN_NAME';
```

And then you can see constraints defined for the respective columns in that tables